# Error being written to file when trying to write output

Tags: python, file, input, output, spell-checking

In this spellchecking program i created i seem to be getting a error when trying to write to the output file.The file is created but instead of the output being written an error `" <_io.TextIOWrapper name='f.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>name "` is.

I've tried looking for solutions.

```
print('Spell checking program for Exam 3 lab')

inputFile  = input('Enter the name of the file to input from: ')

outputFile = input('Enter the name of the file to output to: ')

f = open("linuxwords.txt", "r")

sent = open(inputFile+ '.txt', "r")

butt = open(outputFile+'.txt', 'w')

word = sent.readline()

print ("mispelled words are:")

while word:

    word = word.lower()
    success = False
    x = word.split()
    y=len(x)
    for i in x:
        success = False
        f = open("linuxwords.txt", "r")
        line = f.readline()
        while line:
            if i == line.strip():
                success = True
                break
            line = f.readline()
        f.close()
        if success == False:
            print (i)
    word = sent.readline()
    with open(outputFile+'.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(butt))
        f.write(i)
    try:
         '''''''
          I'm sure my mistake is here, idk
         '''''''
        f = open(outputFile, "w")
        f.write(i)
    except:
         print('The file',outputFile, 'did not open.')


sent.close()
```

''''''
Result below
''''''''
Spell checking program for Exam 3 lab
Enter the name of the file to input from: spw
Enter the name of the file to output to: f
misspelled words are:
deks
chris
delatorre
huis
lst

Comment: That's not an error, that's a default string representation of an object. Double check your data that you're trying to write to file.

Comment: Welcome to [so], Chris! Do take advantage of the formatting features available here, and put some time into your questions. The more time you spend writing a question, the easier it is to answer. (It's not unusual for it to take more than 15 minutes to research enough to provide an [mcve] for a question, for example.)

Answer (score 3):

```
f = open(outputFile)
f.write(i)
```

You're opening the file for *reading*, and then trying to *write* to it.

Comment: Yes, you can see from the [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) that `r` for readonly is the default mode.